# Optimising subsetting with for loop in R

Tags: r, gtfs

I'm using R and RStudio to analyse GTFS public transport feeds and to create timetable range plots using ggplot2. The code currently works fine but is quite slow, which is problematic when working with very big CSVs as is often the case here.

The slowest part of the code is as follows (with some context): a for loop that iterates through the data frame and subsets each unique trip into a temporary data frame from which the extreme arrival and departure values (first & last rows) are extracted:

```
# Creates an empty df to contain trip_id, trip start and trip end times
Trip_Times <- data.frame(Trip_ID = character(), Departure = character(), Arrival = character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

# Creates a vector containing all trips of the analysed day
unique_trips = unique(stop_times$trip_id)

# Iterates through stop_times for each unique trip_id and populates previously created data frame
for (i in seq(from = 1, to = length(unique_trips), by = 1)) {
  temp_df <- subset(stop_times, trip_id == unique_trips[i])
  Trip_Times[nrow(Trip_Times) + 1, ] <- c(temp_df$trip_id[[1]], temp_df$departure_time[[1]], temp_df$arrival_time[[nrow(temp_df)]])
}
```

The `stop_times` df looks as follows with some feeds containing over 2.5 million lines giving around 200k unique trips, hence 200k loop iterations...

```
head(stop_times)
trip_id arrival_time departure_time stop_sequence
1 011_0840101_A14      7:15:00        7:15:00             1
2 011_0840101_A14      7:16:00        7:16:00             2
3 011_0840101_A14      7:17:00        7:17:00             3
4 011_0840101_A14      7:18:00        7:18:00             4
5 011_0840101_A14      7:19:00        7:19:00             5
6 011_0840101_A14      7:20:00        7:20:00             6
```

Would anyone be able to advise me how to optimise this code in order to obtain faster results. I don't believe `apply` can be used here but I may well be wrong.

Comment: One improvement is to generate your data.frame ahead of time, rather than grow it in each iteration. Something like `myRows <- length(unique_trips); Trip_Times <- data.frame(Trip_ID=character(myRows), Departure=character(myRows), Arrival=character(myRows), stringsAsFactors=FALSE) `. Then just fill it in. This reduces the number of copies that R has to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be straightforward with `dplyr`...

```
library(dplyr)

Trip_Times <- stop_times %>%
              group_by(trip_id) %>%
              summarise(departure_time=first(departure_time),
                        arrival_time=last(arrival_time))
```

Comment: Wow, that works really well. What used to take 5 hours now takes 5 minutes! 
I really must learn more about dplyr...

Once again, many thanks

Comment: Yes, it is well worth learning dplyr. The RStudio cheat sheet is quite a useful starting point. Enjoy your extra 4h 55m!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(stop_times)[, .(departure_time = departure_time[1L], 
                    arrival_time = arrival_time[.N]) , by = trip_id]
```